# ajax load content render in php return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, slim

I'm using ajax call api return json and render html append to page like below.
I have question is is possible after post parameter to api function then api function render in php then return rendered data to js, js just only append?

Because there is to much html structure if i write in js so difficult to read. Wondering most people how to do this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: public_path+'/api_for_ajax/category/'+category_id+'/'+visible+'/'+rows_perpage+'/'+page,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    async: false
}).done(function(response) {
    var response = JSON.parse(response);
    $(data_article.article).each(function(i, each_data_article) {
        var output = '<div class="article-list"><a href="'+public_path+'/article/'+each_data_article.id+'">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="'+public_path+'/assets/thumbnails/'+each_data_article.thumbnail.thumbnail_id+'/'+each_data_article.thumbnail.file_name+'.'+each_data_article.thumbnail.file_format+'" alt=""></div>
        <div class="subject">'+each_data_article.subject+'</div>
        </a></div>';
       // append
    });
});
```

api

```
$data_select_category_id_page = $this->article_model->select_category_id_page($response_message, $category_id, $visible, $rows_perpage, $page);

$data = array();
$data['article'] = $data_select_category_id_page;

echo json_encode($data);
```

I tried in slim framework, it not work why??

api

```
$data_select_category_id_page = $this->article_model->select_category_id_page($response_message, $category_id, $visible, $rows_perpage, $page);

// 1
$app->render('frontstage/article/page_view.php', array(
  'data_select_category_id_page' => $data_select_category_id_page,
  )
);


// 2
return <<<HTML
<div><?php print_r($data_select_category_id_page);?></div>
HTML;
```

layout

```
<?php $column_count = 1; ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($data['article']['article'] as $i => $each_article) { ?>
        <?php if ($i >= 4) { ?>
    <div class="article-list">
        <a href="<?php echo $uri['public']; ?>/article/<?php echo $each_article['id']; ?>">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $uri['public']; ?>/assets/thumbnails/<?php echo $each_article['thumbnail']['thumbnail_id']?>/<?php echo $each_article['thumbnail']['file_name']?>.<?php echo $each_article['thumbnail']['file_format']?>" alt=""></div>
            <div class="subject"><?php echo $each_article['subject'];?></div>

            <div class="category-list-container">
            <?php foreach ($each_article['category'] as $each_article_category) { ?>
                <div class="category-list"><?php echo $each_article_category['subject']; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <?php 
            $old_date = $each_article['create_at'];
            $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
            $new_date = date('d M Y', $old_date_timestamp);
        ?>
        <div class="create-at"><?php echo $new_date;?></div>
    </a>
</div>
<?php if (($column_count % 4) == 0) { ?>
<div class="clear"></div></div><div class="row">
<?php } ?>
<?php $column_count++;?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: well, thats an option also, let the server build the markup response, and then receive it as html instead of json

Comment: What @ghost suggested. Why not either let the data already be played out  as html and just append it in a single variable

Comment: is this codeigniter?

Comment: @Ghost slim framewrok

Comment: @Dorvalla I tried render data in php I use slim, can you show me example how to? even not with slim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have the server return the html rendered rather than JSON.

```
$.post( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

Where test.php returns some kind of HTML data.

The test.php code will contain the logic to render the relevant html.  Using the OP example as the logic, would look something like (untested) :

```
$public_path = '/sitepath/';
foreach($data_select_category_id_page as $article)
{
   echo '<div class="aricle-list"><a href="' . $public_path . '/article/' . $article->id . '">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="' . $public_path . '/assets/thumbnails/' . $article->thumbnail_id . '/' . $article->thumbnail->file_name . '.' . $article->thumbnail->file_format . '" alt=""></div>
    <div class="subject">' . $article->subject . '</div>
    </a></div>';
}
```

Or alternatively use a layout to render the html.

Beaware that the size of the rendered html being returned from the server is large than JSON.

Comment: but I have problem how render in php I tried above, but not work can you show me some example?

Comment: @user1775888 I have updated the answer with a sample.  You simply need to echo the relevant html instead of the JSON.  You can use simplified layout to output the html if you prefer.

Comment: thanks for reply, how to use a layout? you mean it is possible to make a independent layout php file and pass array to it and then return to js?

Comment: Try something like - http://willisbored.com/2011/04/04/tutorial-slim-php-view-templates/ . Assign the correct data to the view, and run it through the renderer.  You should get HTML returned as a result, and this can then be appended to the page.